# kernel user-space input output (uio): how to hook the writes of the user-space application?

Tags: memory, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, mmap

The longer version of the same question:

A kernel module maps into a /dev file the physical memory of a hardware device. An user-space application maps that /dev file into memory to write in the corresponding physical registers.

To virtualize the hardware, same user-space interface should be provided (a memory-mappable /dev file), but the reads and the writes made by the user-space application should be hooked.

How to achieve that?